# JavaScript vibration script modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement a vibration system when users enter on my site.

I have used this code:

```js
var warning = function() {
  //
}
setTimeout(warning, 100);
// Play notification
if (window.navigator && window.navigator.vibrate) {
  // Vibrate once for 1 second
  navigator.vibrate(1000);
  // Wait 1 second than display warning
} else {
  // Stop vibrating
  navigator.vibrate(0);
}
```

It does vibrate for one time only. But it needs to be at least 3 times vibration so that the visitors can feel it.

How can I do this with this script?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a vibration pattern by [passing an array to `navigator.vibrate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/vibrate#Syntax), where elements denote a sequence of "vibration" and "rest" periods in milliseconds.

```
// Vibrate three times for 1 second each, with 100ms pauses
navigator.vibrate([1000, 100, 1000, 100, 1000])
```

You also don't need an `else` clause, because vibration stops automatically when playback has completed.

```js
function warning() {
  alert('Warning!')
}

// Play notification
if (window.navigator && window.navigator.vibrate) {
  // Vibrate three times for 1 second each, with 100ms pauses
  navigator.vibrate([1000, 100, 1000, 100, 1000])
  // Wait 1 second, then display warning
  setTimeout(warning, 1000)
}
```

(Note that I don't personally think I would appreciate a website doing this on load.)

Comment: I don't need an alert on this script since I already have one on the other side.

So what would be script then? 

I think
<script>

// Play notification
if (window.navigator && window.navigator.vibrate) {
  // Vibrate three times for 1 second each, with 100ms pauses
  navigator.vibrate([1000, 100, 1000, 100, 1000])
}

</script>


Right?

Comment: Yes, just remove the `warning` function as you see fit, and that should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot.

Can I please have your skype (if you don't mind).

Don't worry, I won't bother you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to pass the value in an array in the following way

It will vibrate thrice with a pause of 250ms between two vibrations

```
navigator.vibrate([1000, 250, 1000, 250, 1000])
```